# List sequential subset elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations, combinatorics

I have an `Array a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`
and I want to subset with 3 elements so the result becomes this:

```
[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]
```

I tried using this script that I found :

```
Array.prototype.combinate = function( iItems, aIn ) {
    if (!aIn) {
        var aIn = new Array();
        this.combinate.aResult = new Array();
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var a = aIn.concat(this[i]);
        var aRest = this.concat(); // Concat with nothing to create copy
        aRest.splice(0, i + 1);

        if(iItems && iItems - 1 <= aRest.length) {
            aRest.combinate(iItems - 1, a);
            if(iItems == 1) this.combinate.aResult.push(a);
        }
    }

    return this.combinate.aResult;
}
```

But this gives all possible subset (and become easily slow when the list becomes big and the search subset is small) - I only need the "sequential" subset like shown above - so like `[1,2,3]` **is ok** - but not `[1,2,4]` ..

Any bright people out there who knows how to do this in JavaScript ..?

Comment: Iterate the array, increment the index, and grab 3 elements in sequential order without going out of bounds.

Comment: Just iterate until `a.length - 3`, and push `a.slice(i, i + 3)` to the result on each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the array in question does not need to be sorted in some way first, I would do it this way:

```
function combinate(arr) {
  var results = [];

  if (arr.length >= 3) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
      var slice = arr.slice(i, i + 3);
      results.push(slice);
    }
  }

  return results;
}
```

As an additional note, I would recommend against adding something like this as a method to the Array prototype. Nothing stopping you from doing so if you need to for some reason, but I would avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
    var combination = new Array(arr[i], arr[i + 1], arr[i + 2]);
    // or this
    // var combination = [arr[i], arr[i + 1], arr[i + 2]];
    // do something with the new array ??
}
```